# How to stop member login from showing as a bounce

Tags: google-analytics

I have a members site and I am looking for a way to stop users who just hits the home page then logs in from showing as bounce in the system?

e.g. the user journey is something like.

www.mywebsite.com -> login.mywebsite.com

So if this happens I would like to be able to either remove the user completely from GA or at lest not have it register as bounce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your login page has the Google Analytics tracking code on it, then the login page will register as a pageview.  The user will have two page views in their session.  With two page views, they won't be counted as a "bounce".

As Moobot points out in the comments, you will have to adjust your Google Analytics tracking code to set cookies for your base domain so that it will track across sub-domains.  [Here is a queston on StackOverflow that has more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865701/google-analytics-for-subdomains-good-practice).

Comment: Will this work with both pages being on separate domains/ sub domains

Comment: Yes.  I use the same analytics code across all my subdomains without issue.

Comment: Yes, but not out of the box. Needs a bit of tweeking to the tracking codes: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite